# Where can I find an EEG signal database for depression (MDD) to use in MATLAB?

Tags: database, matlab, signals

I need EEG signals from depressive patients and from normal people to compare them using EEGLAB in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small list of publicly available EEG datasets. You can use eeglab to process these data. Some of it should contain depression data. Just google the provider and reference together, you should be able to find the links easily.

[image: EEG Dataset Table]